# To record sounds from 3.5 - 3.5 mm audio in Audacity of OSX?

Tags: macos, audio, recording, macbook-air, audacity

I have this kind of setting

- 3.5 - 3.5 mm cable from Macbook Air to iPhone 4s
- put some sounds like Spotify on and play
- want to record this sound in Audacity of Macbook

My audacity

[image]

My setup

[image]

I think I should change some of those scroll up things. 
I have changed all logical things there but cannot get signals from phone to computer. 
Only sounds from microphone.

The newest OSX cannot find the device in Settings > Sound

[image]

**How can you record the sounds from your phone through 3.5-3.5 mm cable in your computer's Audacity?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to select the "Line" or "Line in" as the recording device in Audacity. If you don't have one it might be disabled.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that the system cannot find the phone when I connect it to my Macbook. How can you find the disabled devices?

Comment: I opened a OSX specific question about this here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140120/to-find-the-disabled-devices-in-osx since this question of this thread is not about OSX but Audacity.

Comment: @ThiefMaster did you realize he is using a Mac, and your answer is about windows?

Comment: This is a good and correct answer. Thank you for your answer @ThiefMaster I solved the OSX problem.

Comment: Ooops, didn't notice that. Where's the [tag:osx] tag? ;)